# How to make maps out of imagery?

Tags: qgis, raster, boundless-suite, raster-conversion

I am working for a client and we chose to use OpenGeo Suite as our system. Our client will be flying a plane over farm land capturing images that we need to put in our system. From my understanding those images will be raster files. (.jpeg- just from a camera)

He will also be having GPS locations with each of the images, but in a separate file.

I can't figure out how to convert those raster files so that I can upload them into the system and be able to view them on an interactive map, in the correct spot.

Comment: Have you looked into georeferencing/orthorectification?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the coordinates of the images aren't stored in the image file itself? I think you'll have to do this manually using methods @Barbarossa mentions. Many cameras these days store location data though, so make sure whether that's available or not. If it is, your job is a lot easier.

Comment: This is his team mate - Nick! Nice to meet you all! We have been tasked with what he said above, and we have been able to load shapefiles into Open Geo Suite, and now we are trying to work just .jpeg files... Another issue is he has NO TEST DATA for us. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know too much on georeferencing, but wouldn't they be able to mosaic the images together (assuming you want 1 overall image) and then use the GPS locations (assuming points) as georeference points?  I am not sure how distorted the end result may be, or if this is a good strategy?

Comment: If we're talking about a person in a plane leaning over and taking pictures straight down (or even worse, at all angled out toward the horizon), then there are number of factors to consider. This is usually done with specialized camera equipment and systems that provide a great deal of location and camera distortion information, and plenty of overlap. If you don't have that you can expect a great deal of inaccuracy in the result. The simplest thing you can do is georeference the images to a known map as suggested. Past that you're looking at orthorectification first, then georeferencing.

Comment: @branco (and recurvata) The gps data recorded will simply be the point from which the image was taken, and with the consumer camera level systems it's not likely to be that accurate or provide altitude information, let alone look angle, etc. At best it gets you an idea of order/relative location from where each image was taken - not so much a georeferencing or ground control point. I had a great example of this as a civil air patrol photo map, but I think it's been taken offline now. Raises a question for OP though - are we mapping the images, or just creating dots on a map that link to them?

Answer (score 2):

In short, you must georeference your images in order to view them in an interactive map. The GPS points provided should be used for this.

I am not familiar with OpenGeoSuite, I do know however that QGIS 2.8.1 (free and open source, tried and tested) has a georeferencer plugin which works perfect for standard georeferencing which I can stand by as I have used it many times before.See http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/advanced_georeferencing.html for tutorial.

In terms of creating a mosaic, if you think it is necessary see the link below for help via QGIS:http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

If there are severe height distortions in your imagery then you may have to look into orthorectification, although you would need elevation data for this. If your image appears to have minimal height distortions then standard georeferencing should be ok.

Hope this helps.